# Movie Clip tracking & setting floor not working properly despite very good solve error

Tags: video, tracking

I'm trying to track this [video clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/199YEi0mIn7twSSb4wUJCDTbhU_Fz4A0q/view?usp=sharing) where I actually got a good solve error of below 0.5 pixels.

[image]

But somehow when I setup the track scene with the *Setup Tracking Scene* button, I am unable to set the floor. Whenever I select any 3 or more markers on the road and click *Floor* button under *Orientation*, it always sets the plane object incorrectly as seen below. It keeps facing the camera instead of lying flat on the road floor. I am not sure if this is related to this scene issue where the camera stops moving at around after frame 525+. Why does it stop moving? As per trackers, they seem to be enough and logical for the solver to be able to determine the 3D spatial equivalent of the video.

[image]

[image]

I made a second attempt with way more markers using *Auto Detect Features* and now the camera moves along the video footage much better but still the *Floor* button doesn't work in Blender 3.6. As you can see below I have selected 3 appropriate markers for the floor, but when I click *Floor*, the floor pops up flat on the camera which is wrong.

[image]

[image]

I made a third attempt, I don't understand why can't Blender get it right? I also noticed the tracker is not on the right spot. Maybe this is related to why I can't get the *Floor* to correctly set...

[image]

[image]

Comment: honestly i tried looking into your problem, but the movie wasn't inside the blend file (i guess because of size problems uploading) but with this is was hard to "see" anything useful. If you could provide a link (maybe another cloud service) with the movie file i would look at it again and try... and even trying your external link to add it ....i failed :(

Comment: i got it in there....but it was vertically and/or horizontally flipped and didn't fit into it ;)