# Struggling to track a circling drone shot

Tags: camera, tracking

I took [that shot](https://www.pexels.com/video/drone-shot-of-snow-covered-structure-on-a-mountain-7592056/) from pexels to track and integrate an object inside of it
(cylindric structure in the middle)

My solve error being a bit below 4, I tried doing a camera motion solve.
I keep getting absurd values in my focal length, optical center offset and lens distortion values.

[image]
[image]

I tried setting up the values manually (like a mavic 2).
But to no avail. I've tracked drone shots before without any issues.

Spent the night tweaking, re-solving, retracking, making multiple saves, etc.
Could I please get some help. I'd be more than happy to add a packed scene if it can make it clearer. I'm using the stable 3.6

Comment: This will not work. I already [tried something similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296492/movie-clip-tracking-setting-floor-not-working-properly-despite-very-good-solve). I think it's a limitation, Blender can only track relatively simple scenes. But please let me know if I was wrong and you made the impossible possible! :)

Comment: Ok I'll try doing it in Nuke then.
Being sure I should find another way actually saves me a lot of time!

Comment: yeah definitely not blender for this type of tracking. i wasted so much time trying to make that type of tracking.